# Flutter: How to show appbar above drawer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am building a flutter app and I don't find how to show appbar above drawer.
I saw many people asking this but anybody solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: GestureDetector(
            child: Text('OPEN'),
            onTap: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            }),
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Drawer(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but there is no way to do it cleaner ?

Comment: small suggestion: replace `GestureDetector` with an `IconButton` to get the ripple effect

Comment: Initially, you are asking drawer, so this is a drawer approach~ instead, if you want more cleaner way, just use slide panel in body, https://pub.dev/packages/slide_panel